# Webcam works in browser, but not in Skype or Cheese

Tags: dell, webcam, xps

I have a Dell XPS 15 l502x, and I want to get my camera to work. It has been working in some previous versions of Ubuntu.

I got no idea why it isn't working, and what to check to find out why. If someone could help me to get it to work would be great :)

When opening Cheese, there is the normal window but black instead of showing what it should. When I'm using Skype and trying to use my camera, the white camera light right beside the camera turns on.

**UPDATE**

I Just tried this site: http://www.testmycam.net/ , And my camera does work on there :/

Could someone please help me to get my camera to work on Skype?

Answer (score 1):

Have the same model and also the same problem. It seem to be a bug but there is currently no solution for it https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cheese/+bug/1268359